# useAsync causes an infinite refresh loop when used with usestate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to assign the value of the interface to the state of the current component after `useAsync`, but this will cause an Infinite Refresh Loop

What are the best practices?

I'm using `useAsync` in react-use

demo:[useAsync](https://codesandbox.io/s/useasync-ructy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please include the relevant code

Comment: [useAsync](https://codesandbox.io/s/useasync-ructy?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `useEffect` hook to update the `state` property.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(value) set(state => ({name: value.name}))
  }, [value])
```

Replacing this:

```
if(value) set(state => ({name: value.name}))
```